# SQL FORCE SORT Columns generated from rows by values contained

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to order the output of a dynamic query, that turns columns into rows, to ensure that only columns with values are generated before the rows with no values. How do I force order on the generation of the columns so the first columns are columns that contain values for particular fields while those with no values for the particular fields are generated at the end of my row?

```
             insert into #PriceSheet
      select  ID, ProductID,SheetNumber ,SheetDesc ,MfgPriceCode,PriceZone

  FROM  ProductPrice
  left join UNITS On SUOM = UOMID

  select @colsUnpivot = stuff((select ','+quotename(C.name)
         from tempdb.sys.columns as C
         where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#PricingSheet') and
               C.name LIKE '%%' 
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

 select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name 
                         + cast(t.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by ProductID 
                                               order by ProductID) rn
                      from #PriceSheet
                    ) t
                     cross apply 
                      tempdb.sys.columns  as C
                   where C.object_id = object_id('tempdb..#PricingSheet') 
                     and C.name Not in ('CreateDate', 'LastModifiedDate')
                   group by c.name, t.rn
                   order by t.rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


       set @query = 'select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID, col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col, val
        from 
        (
          select  
       cast(ProductID              as varchar(50))ProductID
      ,cast(SheetNumber              as varchar(50))SheetNumber
      ,cast(SheetDesc              as varchar(50))SheetDesc
      ,cast(MfgPriceCode              as varchar(50))MfgPriceCode
      ,cast(PriceZone              as varchar(50))PriceZone 
       row_number() over(partition by productid order by productid) rn

          from #PriceSheet
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ('+ @colspivot +')
      ) p'
```

Say for instance, to generate the columns first for rows that have SheetNumber not equal to NULL and then the NULLS afterward.

Comment: add your sample query, please!

Comment: Are you saying you want the columns in a different order PER ROW?

Comment: Yes. I want the columns generated in the other I specify, that is the columns with values to be created in the row before the columns without values in them.

Comment: The code has been updated a bit but still have not had any luck gaining more control over the columns generated from my order temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
      from
      (
        select ProductID,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) new_col,
            val
        from 
        (
          select   
           Cast (ProductID as NVarchar(3072)) ProductID
           ,Cast (SheetNumber  as NVarchar(3072)) SheetNumber 
           ,Cast (SheetDesc   as NVarchar(3072)) SheetDesc 
           ,Cast (MfgPriceCode as NVarchar(3072)) MfgPriceCode
           ,Cast (PriceZone as NVarchar(3072))  PriceZone  
            ,row_number() over(partition by ProductID order by Case When SheetNumber Is Null Then 1 Else 0 End, ProductID) rn
          from MainPricesheet
     ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ([SheetNumber],[SheetDesc],[MfgPriceCode],[PriceZone])
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for new_col in
          ([SheetNumber1],[SheetDesc1],[MfgPriceCode1],[PriceZone1],
           [SheetNumber2],[SheetDesc2],[MfgPriceCode2],[PriceZone2],
           [SheetNumber3],[SheetDesc3],[MfgPriceCode3],[PriceZone3],
           [SheetNumber4],[SheetDesc4],[MfgPriceCode4],[PriceZone4],
           [SheetNumber5],[SheetDesc5],[MfgPriceCode5],[PriceZone5],
           [SheetNumber6],[SheetDesc6],[MfgPriceCode6],[PriceZone6],
           [SheetNumber7],[SheetDesc7],[MfgPriceCode7],[PriceZone7],
           [SheetNumber8],[SheetDesc8],[MfgPriceCode8],[PriceZone8],
           [SheetNumber9],[SheetDesc9],[MfgPriceCode9],[PriceZone9],
           [SheetNumber10],[SheetDesc10],[MfgPriceCode10],[PriceZone10],
           [SheetNumber11],[SheetDesc11],[MfgPriceCode11],[PriceZone11],
           [SheetNumber12],[SheetDesc12],[MfgPriceCode12],[PriceZone12],
           [SheetNumber13],[SheetDesc13],[MfgPriceCode13],[PriceZone13],
           [SheetNumber14],[SheetDesc14],[MfgPriceCode14],[PriceZone14],
           [SheetNumber15],[SheetDesc15],[MfgPriceCode15],[PriceZone15],
           [SheetNumber16],[SheetDesc16],[MfgPriceCode16],[PriceZone16],
           [SheetNumber17],[SheetDesc17],[MfgPriceCode17],[PriceZone17],
           [SheetNumber18],[SheetDesc18],[MfgPriceCode18],[PriceZone18],
           [SheetNumber19],[SheetDesc19],[MfgPriceCode19],[PriceZone19],
           [SheetNumber20],[SheetDesc20],[MfgPriceCode20],[PriceZone20],
           [SheetNumber21],[SheetDesc21],[MfgPriceCode21],[PriceZone21])
      ) p
```